How to instruct the CMake to use a specific CMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET?
vcpkg uses CMake internally to build stuff and on my system, the CMake invoked by the vcpkg, attempts to use the wrong version of the SDK and errors out (I can see its attempt to access a non-existent SDK file path in SysInternals' ProcessMonitor when the linker attempts to access the ucrtd.lib file, while the CMake is doing its job).
Setting the CMake's environment variable to the correct toolset: CMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET=v142, does not work.
Setting the vcpkg's environment variable to the correct toolset: VCPKG_PLATFORM_TOOLSET=v142, does not work.
However, setting the CMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET:INTERNAL=v142 inside the CMakeCache.txt works ! ( it gets rid of the error temporarily ).
Q: Is there some kind of configuration file somewhere which instructs the CMake( the one used by vcpkg) to permanently use a specific CMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET ?
BTW: I encountered this problem when executing the command vcpkg install opencl in Windows x64 from the x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019.
Specifically, this happens when the vcpkg tests the functionality of the compiler & linker in:
..vcpkg/downloads/tools/cmake-3.30.1-windows/cmake-3.30.1-windows-i386/share/cmake-3.30/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:
# Distributed under the OSI-approved BSD 3-Clause License.  See accompanying
# file Copyright.txt or https://cmake.org/licensing for details.


if(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_FORCED)
  # The compiler configuration was forced by the user.
  # Assume the user has configured all compiler information.
  set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS TRUE)
  return()
endif()

include(CMakeTestCompilerCommon)

# work around enforced code signing and / or missing executable target type
set(__CMAKE_SAVED_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE ${CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE})
if(_CMAKE_FEATURE_DETECTION_TARGET_TYPE)
  set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE ${_CMAKE_FEATURE_DETECTION_TARGET_TYPE})
endif()

# Remove any cached result from an older CMake version.
# We now store this in CMakeCCompiler.cmake.
unset(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS CACHE)

# Try to identify the ABI and configure it into CMakeCCompiler.cmake
include(${CMAKE_ROOT}/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerABI.cmake)
CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ABI(C ${CMAKE_ROOT}/Modules/CMakeCCompilerABI.c)
if(CMAKE_C_ABI_COMPILED)
  # The compiler worked so skip dedicated test below.
  set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS TRUE)
  message(STATUS "Check for working C compiler: ${CMAKE_C_COMPILER} - skipped")
endif()

# This file is used by EnableLanguage in cmGlobalGenerator to
# determine that that selected C compiler can actually compile
# and link the most basic of programs.   If not, a fatal error
# is set and cmake stops processing commands and will not generate
# any makefiles or projects.
if(NOT CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS)
  PrintTestCompilerStatus("C")
  __TestCompiler_setTryCompileTargetType()
  string(CONCAT __TestCompiler_testCCompilerSource
    "#ifdef __cplusplus\n"
    "# error \"The CMAKE_C_COMPILER is set to a C++ compiler\"\n"
    "#endif\n"
    "#if defined(__CLASSIC_C__)\n"
    "int main(argc, argv)\n"
    "  int argc;\n"
    "  char* argv[];\n"
    "#else\n"
    "int main(int argc, char* argv[])\n"
    "#endif\n"
    "{ (void)argv; return argc-1;}\n")
  # Clear result from normal variable.
  unset(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS)
  # Puts test result in cache variable.
  try_compile(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS
    SOURCE_FROM_VAR testCCompiler.c __TestCompiler_testCCompilerSource
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE __CMAKE_C_COMPILER_OUTPUT)
  unset(__TestCompiler_testCCompilerSource)
  # Move result from cache to normal variable.
  set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS ${CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS})
  unset(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS CACHE)
  __TestCompiler_restoreTryCompileTargetType()
  if(NOT CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS)
    PrintTestCompilerResult(CHECK_FAIL "broken")
    string(REPLACE "\n" "\n  " _output "${__CMAKE_C_COMPILER_OUTPUT}")
    message(FATAL_ERROR "The C compiler\n  \"${CMAKE_C_COMPILER}\"\n"
      "is not able to compile a simple test program.\nIt fails "
      "with the following output:\n  ${_output}\n\n"
      "CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.")
  endif()
  PrintTestCompilerResult(CHECK_PASS "works")
endif()

# Try to identify the compiler features
include(${CMAKE_ROOT}/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerSupport.cmake)
CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_SUPPORT(C)

# Re-configure to save learned information.
configure_file(
  ${CMAKE_ROOT}/Modules/CMakeCCompiler.cmake.in
  ${CMAKE_PLATFORM_INFO_DIR}/CMakeCCompiler.cmake
  @ONLY
  )
include(${CMAKE_PLATFORM_INFO_DIR}/CMakeCCompiler.cmake)

if(CMAKE_C_SIZEOF_DATA_PTR)
  foreach(f ${CMAKE_C_ABI_FILES})
    include(${f})
  endforeach()
  unset(CMAKE_C_ABI_FILES)
endif()

set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE ${__CMAKE_SAVED_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE})
unset(__CMAKE_SAVED_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE)
unset(__CMAKE_C_COMPILER_OUTPUT)



When the compiler & linker are tested  by this statement:
try_compile(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS
  SOURCE_FROM_VAR testCCompiler.c __TestCompiler_testCCompilerSource
  OUTPUT_VARIABLE __CMAKE_C_COMPILER_OUTPUT)

The linker looks for the ucrtd.lib in the wrong path (a nonexistent path from a different SDK version) and errors out with:
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'ucrtd.lib'

